# Dc js error while filtering bar chart

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Why some plots appear like this?
Looks like there is a cap on Y axis...

[image]
[image]

```
chart
        .width(400)
        .height(200)
        .dimension(dimension)
        .group(group)
        .transitionDuration(500)
        .yAxisLabel('# count')
        .xAxisLabel('x')
        .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([-3, 3]))
        .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 60000]))
        .elasticY(true)
        .filterOnBrushEnd(true)
        .yAxis()
        .ticks(4);
```

Comment: Any chance you can put together a working example we can look at?

Comment: It would be difficult to put on jsfiddle...  I´m using a ton of data, 200k records...  What I can tell is that i´m using crossfilter 1.4, and dc.js with support for > 32 dimensions and filterOnBrushEnd commits

Comment: You're much more likely to get an answer if you can recreate an example. Using partial data is fine as long as it shows the problem.

Comment: I will try anyway...

Comment: I´m having a hard time setting a working example on jsfiffle... However, I figured out that the problem only appears when working with decimal values on x axis...

Comment: fixed!... Bars were overlapping...  used xUnits() method to ajust

Comment: Ah yes, `XUnits` is often a cause of bad bar widths.